# Remove a recurring substring from an entire column excel-VBA

Tags: excel, replace, trim, vba

I have a column called "Name", whose entries have either

preceding the part of the row entry that I need. so for example

"Name: *{white space}*      ABC Retailers" instead of "ABC Retailers"

or

"ame: *{white space}*    XYZ Suppliers" instead of "XYZ Suppliers"

I just want to get rid of the "Name:" and "ame:" from these row entries, and then also the whitespace to the left.

How exactly would I do that?

I tried using `Replace`, starting off like this:

```
Sub fix_names()
    'declare variables
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Range("B2:B3781")

    'count rows
    noRows = Range("B2:b3781").Rows.Count

    'begin clean up operation
    For i = 1 To noRows
        arr(i) = (Replace(arr(i), "Name:", ""))
    Next i

End Sub
```

but no avail. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: A formula would do it `=TRIM(MID(B2,SEARCH(":",B2) +1, LEN(B2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment a simple formula will do it:

```
=TRIM(MID(B2,SEARCH(":",B2) +1, LEN(B2)))
```

---

If you want it in vba then:

```
Sub fix_names()
'declare variables
Dim i as long
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Range("B2:B3781")

'begin clean up operation
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    arr(i, 1) = Trim(Mid(arr(i, 1), WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Find(":", arr(i, 1)), 1) + 1))
Next i
Range("B2:B3781").Value = arr
End Sub
```

The issue is that even though you are loading the array with only one column it is still a two dimensional array and must be treated as such.

Comment: Thanks, the formula worked and was much less of a hassle! I tried using your VBA code but it gave me an error:

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment (Error 450).

Although I do not really needed it, I want to solve this just for the sake of practicing my VBA skills. I will attempt it some more and post an update here if/when I get the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: crikey, i've deleted the code/file, but from memory it was the forloop.

Comment: That's interestng.  It works for me.  But I am glad the formula worked for you.